# Jupyter Notebook launches the start page with MacVim instead of Safari

Tags: macos, safari, html

So at some point MacVim got associated with HTML pages, and since than when I launch jupyter it defaults to opening the landing page with MacVim instead of a browser.

I have changed the "Opens with" for all HTML files, and indeed if I double click an HTML file it properly loads the page in Safari, but the Jupyter issue remains as is, which is annoying. I have noticed that the icon displayed for HTML files is still MacVim's icon, as if it's the default application.

Has anyone else experienced this? If so, any tips on how to resolve the situation?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Here is how I fixed:

It seems that using the OpenWith option only works once. To change the default application permanently I did the following:

Select an HTML file and right-click on it. Then you select **Get Info** and in the **Open with** section, select a browser as the default application and click on the **Change All**... button.

I hope it helps